# Make new UINavigationController then empty stack of old navigation controller programatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

Without using storyboards, I want to:

1. Create a UINavigationController (let's call it NC_A) in the app delegate, then push a bunch of UIViewControllers onto it. (This doesn't need to be explained. It's just step one.)
2. Then, from the last UIViewController on the stack, I want to jump off to a new UINavigationController (NC_B).
3. After the new NC_B's root view is shown, behind the scenes on NC_A pop back to NC_A's root view so that when I return to it, the root view is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, prepare `NC_A`:

```
let rootA = UIViewController(...)
let navA = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootA)
```

`navA` should be your window's root view controller or presented some other way.  Push a bunch of view controllers on `navA`.

Now prepare `NC_B`.  We will present it modally on top of your `NC_A` stack.  We can use the completion handler on `presentViewControllerAnimated` to pop `NC_A` back to its root view controller.

```
let rootB = UIViewController(...)

let navB = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootB)

navA.presentViewController(navB, animated: true) { () -> Void in
    navA.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Now, when you call `dismissViewControllerAnimated` on `NC_B`, `NC_A` will be popped to its root view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Here is objective-c solution: you can put both NC_A and NC_B navigation controllers in master navigation controller and let that handle the switching.

**1. Setup:**

```
UIViewController * rootVC_A = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController * NC_A = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: rootVC_A];

UIViewController * rootVC_B = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
UINavigationController * NC_B = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: rootVC_B];

UINavigationController * RootNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController: NC_A];
```

**2.Pushing to NC_A**

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
{
    UIViewController * randomVC = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [NC_A pushViewController:randomVC animated: true];
}
```

**3. Jump to NC_B**

```
[RootNavigationController pushViewController: NC_B animated: YES];
```

**4. Pop Back NC_A**

```
[NC_A popToRootViewController];
```

Comment: This question was tagged with Swift, why would you post an Objective-C solution?

Comment: I can convert this solution to swift when I'm around my Mac, the idea is exactly the same, so I just posted objective c, which I'm more comfortable with

Comment: I don't see how translating your answer into Swift will add anything that isn't included in my earlier answer which is already in Swift.

Comment: Your solution is presenting the second navigation controller modally whereas my solution is wrapping it around a top navigation controller? Personally I think wrapping the two in main navigation controller is more robust solution since it lets you do the same for third and fourth navigation controllers same way, if he needs to later on...